# Can't programically open a word docx with spaces in the file name using COM in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, com, tcpdf, phpword

I am creating a document management system, and I need word to open a docx file and convert to PDF, it is working fine but with one annoying issue, it will not open a docx file with spaces in the filename, if I give it a filename with underscores or no spaces it works fine.

Here is my code.

```
$destinationPath = 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/approvals/'.$pdffilename.'';


$assembly = 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c';
$class = 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass';

$w = new DOTNET($assembly, $class);
$w->visible = false;

$fn = 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/approvals/'.$filename.'';

$w->Documents->Open($fn);

// Save as PDF
$XlFixedFormatTypePDF = 17;                       $w->ActiveDocument->ExportAsFixedFormat($destinationPath, $XlFixedFormatTypePDF, false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, true, true, 2, true, true, true);

// close the application and release the COM object

$w->quit(false);
```

The error I get is:-

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:** Microsoft Word
> **Description:** Sorry, we couldn’t find your file. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

I looked at the variable `$fn` and it is giving the full path filename and ext to COM, but COM doesn't like the spaces, I have tried a variety of brackets and a few other things but I am open to suggestions, can't seem to find the solution, I have had a look at the Microsoft site for COM handling and even they only use files with no spaces.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhf98b5c.aspx

I tried PHPWord and TCPDF and nearly had a mental breakdown, the referencing did not make sence to alot of other people either and quite a few people had issues getting it to work properly, so tried doing it via the MS COM way and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around for this using a batch file which does a rename removing the spaces and adding underscores, then reverting them in another folder when they have been converted to a pdf, but please if anyone can resolve the above issue with COM not accepting spaces in file names then hats off to you.